# A problem with manipulating layout within a function as an argument; view.editText must not be null

Tags: android, kotlin

I have created a method to be reused on 4 occasions so that I reduce on the amount of copy-pasted code I'm using.
For some reason, when the code is made into a function, it no longer works.

It works without being a function.

```
    private fun onEditTextAnimation(view: View, b: Boolean) {
        if (b) {
            view.customEditTextBoxMain.layoutParams.height = pxToDP(35)
            view.customEditTextBoxHint.layoutParams.height = pxToDP(15)
            view.customEditTextBoxHint.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            view.redLine.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }
        if (!b) {
            view.customEditTextBoxMain.layoutParams.height = pxToDP(50)
            view.customEditTextBoxHint.visibility = View.GONE
            view.redLine.visibility = View.GONE
        }
    }


// THIS HERE IS THE FUNCTION BEING USED IN A PLACE WHERE THE FUNCTIONS'S BODY WORKED WITHOUT BEING EXTRACTED INTO A FUNCTION
// THIS HERE IS THE FUNCTION BEING USED IN A PLACE WHERE THE FUNCTIONS'S BODY WORKED WITHOUT BEING EXTRACTED INTO A FUNCTION


        jiken0.customEditTextBoxMain.setOnFocusChangeListener { view, b -> onEditTextAnimation(view, b) }

// THIS HERE IS THE FUNCTION BEING USED IN A PLACE WHERE THE FUNCTIONS'S BODY WORKED WITHOUT BEING EXTRACTED INTO A FUNCTION. BELOW ARE THE OTHER 3 FUNCTIONS FOR WHICH I INTENDED THE EXTRACTED FUNCTION
// THIS HERE IS THE FUNCTION BEING USED IN A PLACE WHERE THE FUNCTIONS'S BODY WORKED WITHOUT BEING EXTRACTED INTO A FUNCTION. BELOW ARE THE OTHER 3 FUNCTIONS FOR WHICH I INTENDED THE EXTRACTED FUNCTION

        jiken1.customEditTextBoxMain.setOnFocusChangeListener { view, b ->
            if (b) {
                jiken1.customEditTextBoxMain.layoutParams.height = pxToDP(35)
                jiken1.customEditTextBoxHint.layoutParams.height = pxToDP(15)
                jiken1.customEditTextBoxHint.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                jiken1.redLine.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }
            if (!b) {
                jiken1.customEditTextBoxMain.layoutParams.height = pxToDP(50)
                jiken1.customEditTextBoxHint.visibility = View.GONE
                jiken1.redLine.visibility = View.GONE
            }
        }

        jiken2.customEditTextBoxMain.setOnFocusChangeListener { view, b ->
            if (b) {
                jiken2.customEditTextBoxMain.layoutParams.height = pxToDP(35)
                jiken2.customEditTextBoxHint.layoutParams.height = pxToDP(15)
                jiken2.customEditTextBoxHint.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                jiken2.redLine.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }
            if (!b) {
                jiken2.customEditTextBoxMain.layoutParams.height = pxToDP(50)
                jiken2.customEditTextBoxHint.visibility = View.GONE
                jiken2.redLine.visibility = View.GONE
            }
        }

        jiken3.customEditTextBoxMain.setOnFocusChangeListener { view, b ->
            if (b) {
                jiken3.customEditTextBoxMain.layoutParams.height = pxToDP(35)
                jiken3.customEditTextBoxHint.layoutParams.height = pxToDP(15)
                jiken3.customEditTextBoxHint.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                jiken3.redLine.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }
            if (!b) {
                jiken3.customEditTextBoxMain.layoutParams.height = pxToDP(50)
                jiken3.customEditTextBoxHint.visibility = View.GONE
                jiken3.redLine.visibility = View.GONE
            }
        }

    }
```

This is the XML of the layout I'm reusing:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:id="@+id/customEditTextBoxMain"
        android:hint="PlaceolderMain"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"/>

    <View
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/redLine"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"/>

    <TextView
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/customEditTextBoxHint"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:hint="PlaceolderHint"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:gravity="left"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Each inclusion of that layout is named "jiken0", "jiken1", and so on.

I would like to reuse this function in the 4 instances that it needs to be used.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your lambda from this:

> ```
> jiken0.customEditTextBoxMain.setOnFocusChangeListener { view, b -> onEditTextAnimation(view, b) }
> ```

to this:

```
jiken0.customEditTextBoxMain.setOnFocusChangeListener { _, b -> onEditTextAnimation(jiken0, b) }
```

---

I believe the issue is that the value of the `view` parameter is not what you expect.

In the versions where you're doing all the work inline, you are consistently referencing views like `jiken0`, `jiken1`, etc. But the `setOnFocusChangeListener()` call is always being invoked on `jiken0.customEditTextBoxMain` or `jiken1.customEditTextBoxMain`. That means that the value of the `view` parameter in the lambda is the `customEditTextBoxMain` view, and not the `jiken0` view.

Comment: Hey, it's interesting how as I was typing out the solution to which I've arrived right now, I got a notification about a new answer having been provided.

You're right with what you've said.
I've cast the "view" variable of that lambda expression into what I know that the parent layout is, and in that way have achieved what I wanted. 

The solution that I've arrived to is posted below!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that I needed to obtain the parent layout of the editText of which the onEditTextAnimation is called, and then cast the "view" from the lamba expression into what that view is (in my case, a custom reusable layout).

adding this line:

```
val r = view.parent as LinearLayout
```

to the beginning of the reusable function solved the issue.
Overall, the finished function code looks like this now.

```
private fun onEditTextAnimation(view: View, b: Boolean) {
    val r = view.parent as LinearLayout
    if (b) {
        r.customEditTextBoxMain.layoutParams.height = pxToDP(35)
        r.customEditTextBoxHint.layoutParams.height = pxToDP(15)
        r.customEditTextBoxHint.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        r.redLine.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }
    if (!b) {
        r.customEditTextBoxMain.layoutParams.height = pxToDP(50)
        r.customEditTextBoxHint.visibility = View.GONE
        r.redLine.visibility = View.GONE
    }
}
```

If you have any clear advice on how I can improve my coding, please do tell.
Thank you.